# How can I globally configure a Cargo profile option?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

With Cargo, I can set a project's development settings to use parallel code generation:

```
[profile.dev]
codegen-units = 8
```

According to [the documentation](http://doc.crates.io/config.html), it should be possible to put this into `~/.cargo/config` to apply this setting to all projects.  This doesn't work for me: it seems that the `.cargo/config` file isn't used at all.  Is there any way to apply such configuration to *every* project I compile?

Comment: The documentation you linked to doesn't list any of the profiles as applicable global configuration; perhaps that is the problem? Since profiles seem pretty project-specific, it seems likely that these files wouldn't even be checked. Have you tried any of the other possible paths?

Comment: Ohh, I hadn't considered that profiles might not be globally configurable.  I haven't tried any other paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set rustflags for all builds or per target in your `.cargo/config` file.

```
[build] # or [target.$triple]
rustflags = ["-Ccodegen-units=4"]
```

To be clear, this will set the codegen-units for all your projects (covered by this .cargo/config) regardless of profile.

To make sure it's actually set, you can also set verbose output in the same file. This will show each rustc command with flags that cargo invokes.

```
[term]
verbose = true
```

Comment: Your answer *almost* answers OPs question, but it's unclear how you'd set this option for the `dev` profile, as requested.

Comment: @Shepmaster The question is a bit ambiguous though. He states you can set it per profile in one project, but then asks how to enable it for 'every project [you] compile'. It's unclear if he wants to use codegen-units for all projects compiling with the dev profile, or just all projects. I'll clarify that this affects all projects regardless of profile.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to create a script to be called instead of `cargo`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $* != *--release*  ]]; then
    # dev build
    export RUSTFLAGS="-C codegen-units=8"
fi

cargo "$@"
```

If you use the full path to `cargo` on the script, you can create a alias

```
alias cargo=/path/to/script
```

and just call `cargo`.