# How can I specify linker flags/arguments in a build script?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm using Rust, [bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/bindgen), and a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to work on some FFI bindings to a library.

This library is built using [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/), so when linking against it, I'd normally pass the `-fopenmp` flag to the compiler.

How can I get this flag to be set by `build.rs` when the library is built by Cargo?

Currently, building using Cargo fails, with the failing command being something like:

```
cc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,noexecstack -m64 -l gomp -l stdc++
...skipping dozens of paths/files...
 -Wl,-Bdynamic -l dl -l rt -l pthread -l gcc_s -l c -l m -l rt -l pthread -l util
```

which fails with hundreds of `undefined reference to 'GOMP_parallel_end'` errors.

Rerunning the generated command above with the `-fopenmp` flag manually added succeeds.

I can specify the flag using `RUSTFLAGS='-C link-args=-fopenmp'` before compiling, but is there a way of specifying it from within `build.rs`?

Comment: I don't understand, rustc is the rust compiler not a C compiler. use `rustc-flags` is pointless in your case.

Comment: You should use [`openmp-sys`](https://crates.io/crates/openmp-sys)

Comment: Yup, reading more closely, `rustc-flags` isn't what I want at all, was just looking for a way of adding flags to the `cc` command that gets called during the build. Will look into `openmp-sys` though, wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: the documentation of openmp-sys tell you how to do it `cc.flag(&env::var("DEP_OPENMP_FLAG").unwrap());`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not building the C code with the `cc` crate (it's built using its own build scripts), so just need the flag to be present when linking agains the built libs (unless the `cc` crate can be used for that, will check).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This feature was [added to Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#extra-link-arg) and [stabilized in Cargo 1.56](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/9557).

Linker arguments can be specified in `build.rs` like so:

```rust
// Pass `-fopenmp` to the linker.
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-fopenmp");
```

Answer (score 27):

You <s>cannot</s> could not. See [the sibling answer from ecstaticm0rse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68824012/155423) for an updated answer.

---

Before then, you can use a Cargo [configuration file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html).

#### .cargo/config

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-fsome-artisanal-option"]
```

#### Execution

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/example)
     Running `rustc ...blah blah blah... -C link-args=-fsome-artisanal-option`
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" ...blah blah blah... "-fsome-artisanal-option"
  = note: clang: error: unknown argument: '-fsome-artisanal-option'
```

See also:

- [How to get the linker to produce a map file using Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39310905/155423)
- [How can I globally configure a Cargo profile option?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32029486/155423)
- [Is it possible to specify `panic = "abort"` for a specific target?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47663961/155423)

Comment: Thanks, that gets me a bit closer. The reason I was trying to specify it in build.rs is that it needs to be conditional, as the library I'm linking against can be built both with/without openmp, which is detected in `build.rs`. Is the only option to write a `.cargo/config` at compile time from within my build.rs which contains different link args as necessary?

Comment: @DaveChallis I don't even know if that would work. What's the harm in adding extra linker flags all the time though? They should just be ignored since none of the symbols are needed.

Comment: true, there should be no harm in it, will go down that route for now.