# How can I determine why a compiled Rust binary requires a specific symbol?

Tags: rust, dynamic-linking

I wrote a program in Rust. When compiled, it requires glibc symbols as well as `secure_getenv`.

```
objdump -T ~/Downloads/redisql_v1.0.1_x86_64.so | grep secure -C 3
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 rewind
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 bind
0000000000000000      D  *UND*  0000000000000000              secure_getenv ### <--- here
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 socket
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_trylock
```

How can I tell which dependencies require this specific function?

Comment: Edited to remove the C part. Usually this kind of things are related to the executable, not the language that is used to write it. I was asking how to determine why a specific symbol is needed in a binary written in plain old C.

Comment: Because it's used, directly or indirectly?

Comment: @Dave, it is used by a dependencies... Which one I don't know and I would like to found out.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell which dependencies require this specific function?

You can find out which code *referenced* it by adding `-Wl,-y,secure_getenv` to the link line.

Comment: Combined with [How can I specify linker flags/arguments in a build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50642574/155423)