# How do I pass the linker the -rlink argument?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, linker-errors

I'm trying to cross compile a rust project with [cross](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross).  My project depends on libcurl.  The linker can find the libcurl .so but not the libraries which it depends on:

I'm running:

```
cross build -vv --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

which gives me:

```
  = note: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: warning: libnghttp2.so.14, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I've already confirmed that the library its looking for exists:

```
root@80a13d68ad84:/# find /usr/lib -name "libnghttp2.so.14"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnghttp2.so.14
```

I've read about rust build scripts [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-searchkindpath), where I can add paths to the library search path, but that has not resolved the issue, this is what my build.rs looks like:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf");
}
```

The error suggests using -rpath or -rpath-link, so how do I configure the rpath in rust?  Or is there a different way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to specify linker arguments by using an environment variable like

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--rpath=..."
```

Cargo allows placing the same kind of flag in the configuration file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642574/how-can-i-specify-linker-flags-arguments-in-a-build-script)) but I'm not sure if cross has the same support for something like that.